# Error 404 KeyNotFound and missing files git - s3 deployment

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So We are busy with a uni project and I have set up automated deployment using aws codePipeline, Github, CodeBuild etc.

I finally got the build stage to work with my buildspec and the deploy is also successful. But I get an error 404 Keynotfound when going to the url.

When I go to the bucket contents this is what I find. It is just something with type file. The angular files aren't here.

Any help?

[image]

This is my buildspec code:

````
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo installing nodejs...
      - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
      - apt-get install -y nodejs
      - echo installing yarn...
      - curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
      - echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
      - apt install --no-install-recommends yarn
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo installing dependencies...
      - npm i -g @angular/cli
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      # - echo testing...
      # - echo building...
      - ng build --prod
artifacts:
  files:
    - "**/*"
  discard-paths: no
  base-directory: dist/ ```
````

Comment: I don't see any call to s3 in the codebuild? Where does it error out due to missing key?

Comment: After I set up the bucket for static website access, and I go to the url I get the 404 NotFound Code: NoSuchKey
Message: The specified key does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.

I had to tick a textbox that said unzip after build in the deploy phase and it worked.